# broom::augment omits columns from data

Tags: r, broom

broom::augment outputs only columns from data that are used in formula. This is problematic behavior, because being able to find something like a respondent id can be very helpful at times. Using the newdata argument could be a workaround, but it still doesn't provide a fix when working with nested data.

Additional explanations in-line:

```r
#simulated glm data
glmdata = data.frame(ID=1:100, A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100)) %>% mutate(response=rbinom(length(ID),1,1/(1+exp(-2*A-3*B))  ))

#fit model, not including the ID variable
glmfit = glm(response~A+B, glmdata,family='binomial')

#ID variable is contained in glm$data
str(glmfit$data)

#works!
head(glmfit$data$ID)


#use broom::augment
augmented = glmfit %>% augment

#does not work, wth broom?!
augmented$ID


#ok ... I could use the newdata argument
augmented = glmfit %>% augment(newdata=glmdata)
augmented$ID


#however, that is a hacky workaround ....

#... and it does not fix the following scenario:

#Let's say I want to use nest


#simulated glm data
glmdata1 = data.frame(segm=1,ID=1:100, A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100)) %>% mutate(response=rbinom(length(ID),1,1/(1+exp(-2*A-3*B))  ))
glmdata2 = data.frame(segm=2,ID=1:100, A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100)) %>% mutate(response=rbinom(length(ID),1,1/(1+exp(-3*A-2*B))  ))

glmdata_nest = rbind(glmdata1,glmdata2) %>% group_by(segm) %>% nest


#fit the two models via map
glmfit_nest= glmdata_nest %>% mutate(model=map(data, glm, formula=response~A+B, family='binomial') )

#run augment via map
glmfit_nest_augmented = glmfit_nest %>% mutate(augmented = map(model,augment))

#ID is not here ...
glmfit_nest_augmented$augmented$ID


#ok, so then we have to use map2 ....
glmfit_nest_augmented = glmfit_nest %>% mutate(augmented = map2(model,data,augment,newdata=.y))

#but even this doesn't work

#also, trying to recycling glm$data does not work
glmfit_nest_augmented = glmfit_nest %>% mutate(augmented = map(model,augment,newdata=.$data))
```

**Update:**
broom developers deliberately choose this inconsistent behavior
https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the `.x`, and `.y` goes with the anonymous function call with `~`

```
glmfit_nest_augmented <-  glmfit_nest %>% 
         mutate(augmented = map2(model,data,~ augment(.x, newdata=.y))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Likewise, `glmfit_nest_augmented <-  glmfit_nest %>% mutate(augmented = map(model,~ augment(., newdata=.$data)))`

Comment: However, shouldn't `augment` have a 'preserve.data' argument or so? I think that would be a lot ... tidier.

Comment: @inferator Regarding the second comment, you could request it as a feature in their github page.  They may or may not implement it or if you really wanted, then create that as a feature and do a PR

Comment: in general `augment` can't "preserve" data, because the data that aren't used in the model aren't typically stored within the object ...